# How could I check if progress bar is full and then open an .bat file?

Tags: c#

I don't know exactly where the code should be put and what code should look like. I need help, because I am very new to c#

```
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Start();
        }

        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.progressBar1.Increment(1);


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.TopMost = true;
        }

        private void ProgressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




        }
    }
}
```

When I try the method from old videos, there is no such a thing as it and it shows that progressBar1 doesn't exist.

Comment: The best thing to do when you're new to a language is to find a good tutorial and _learn_. Do not simply copy and paste some code and expect it to work. Otherwise, you'll be disappointed often and will feel frustrated very quickly.

Comment: If (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum) ...

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the `progressBar1.Value`

```
// progressBar1.Value = 0;
// progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
// progressBar1.Maximum = 100; 

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
    if(progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum){
        Process.Start("c:\\file.bat");
    }
}
```

Comment: 100 might not be the top value.

Comment: Right now, when I drop it into my code I am catching 7 errors. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Ionicjohn, I don't know what error you are having. Also don't forget to stop Incrementing.

Comment: @Ionicjohn from your comments i think you not create a ProgressBar object called "progressBar1". If you have create a progressbar in your project read its name and substitute "progressBar1" with that name.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
  If (progressBar1.Value >= progressBar1.Maximum)
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```